# iReport issue in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm using netbeans IDE 8.0.2 and I'm trying to create a report using iReport ... It all worked good until I started the java code :

```
String reportName = "report path";
        InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(reportName);
        try {
            JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(is, null, conn); }
```

Netbeans won't found JasperPrint and JasperFillManager ... is it true that iReport is no more compatible with Netbeans 8+ .... And if yes , is there any other Report Designer plugin ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using netbeans IDE 8.0.2 too, with the iReport 5.6.0 plugin.
In order to use iReport plugin you need to add a new library to your project, tha one that installs the plugin (JasperReports 3.0.1) doesn't work, it doesn't include the package net.sf.jasperreports that contains the classes JasperPrint, JasperReport, etc.

So you must create a new library with all the contents from the lib and dist folders of your unzipped JasperReport5.6.0 library, then you can add it to your proyect and fix your imports.

(You may not need all the jar files in the lib and dist folder, usually, just the jasperreports-5.6.0, commons-*, groovy-all, iText and poi-3*).